# How do refresh my UITableView after reading data from FirebaseFirestore with a SnapShotListener?

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, uikit

UPDATE at the bottom.

I have followed the UIKit section of [this Apple iOS Dev Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/saving-new-reminders), up to and including the Saving New Reminders section. The tutorials provide full code for download at the beginning of each section.

But, I want to get FirebaseFirestore involved. I have some other Firestore projects that work, but I always thought that I was doing something not quite right, so I'm always looking for better examples to learn from.

This is how I found Peter Friese's 3-part YT series, "[Build a To-Do list with Swift UI and Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDde7TqKCpk&t=19s)". While I'm not using SwiftUI, I figured that the Firestore code should probably work with just a few changes, as he creates a Repository whose sole function is to interface between app and Firestore. No UI involved. So, following his example, I added a `ReminderRepository`.

It doesn't work, but I'm **so** close. The `UITableView` looks empty but I know that the records are being loaded.

Stepping through in the debugger, I see that the first time the `numberOfRowsInSection` is called, the data hasn't been loaded from the Firestore, so it returns 0. But, eventually the code *does* load the data. I can see each `Reminder` as it's being mapped and at the end, all documents are loaded into the `reminderRepository.reminders` property.

But I can't figure out how to get the `loadData()` to make the table reload later.

ReminderRepository.swift

```
    class ReminderRepository {
      let remindersCollection = Firestore.firestore()
          .collection("reminders").order(by: "date")

      var reminders = [Reminder]()

      init() {
        loadData()
      }

      func loadData() {
        print ("loadData")
        remindersCollection.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
                self.reminders = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                    do {
                        let reminder = try document.data(as: Reminder.self)
                        print ("loadData: ", reminder?.title ?? "Unknown")
                        return reminder
                    } catch {
                        print (error)
                    }
                    return nil
                }
            }
            print ("loadData: ", self.reminders.count)
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference from the Apple code is that in the ListDataSource.swift file, I added:

```
   var remindersRepository: ReminderRepository

   override init() {
     remindersRepository = ReminderRepository()
   }
```

and all `reminders` references in that file have been changed to

`remindersRepository.reminders`.

Do I need to provide a callback for the `init()`? How? I'm still a little iffy on the matter.

UPDATE: Not a full credit solution, but getting closer.

I added two lines to `ReminderListViewController.viewDidLoad()` as well as the referenced function:

```
    refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshTournaments(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

@objc
private func refreshTournaments(_ sender: Any) {
    tableView.reloadData()
    refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}
```

Now, when staring at the initial blank table, I pull down from the top and it refreshes. Now, how can I make it do that automatically?

Comment: you can force reloading data by simply calling yourTableView.reloadData()

Comment: Yes, but where? The logical place is in the repository when the `reminders` property is populated from firestore, but that class knows nothing about the UI, so it knows nothing about `tableView`.

Comment: Well , in my opinion loading `UITableViewDataSource` should be part of your Controller part (propably `UIViewController`) but you can notify the controller to reload `UITableView` by delegating with 'delegate pattern' from your repository (or using notification, but I prefer delegates) . If you implement delegate pattern correctly , there would be no depencencies and separation of concerns will be satisfied.

Comment: I'm starting with Apple's code base. Where in their code should I make the changes you suggest? Also, I don't have a `UIViewController`, I have a `UITableViewController` so I believe the delegate and datasource are already set.

Comment: I added further explanation into answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly create some `ReminderRepositoryDelegate` protocol, that will handle communication between you Controller part (in your case `ReminderListDataSource` ) and your model part (in your case `ReminderRepository` ). Then load data by delegating controller after `reminder` is set. here are some steps:

1. creating delegate protocol.

   ```
    protocol ReminderRepositoryDelegate: AnyObject {
    func reloadYourData()
   ```

   }
2. Conform `ReminderListDataSource`  to delegate protocol:

   ```
    class ReminderListDataSource: UITableViewDataSource, ReminderRepositoryDelegate {
    func reloadYourData() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
   ```

   }
3. Add delegate weak variable to ReminderRepository that will weakly hold your controller.

   ```
      class ReminderRepository {
            let remindersCollection = Firestore.firestore()
                .collection("reminders").order(by: "date")

            var reminders = [Reminder]()
            weak var delegate: ReminderRepositoryDelegate?
            init() {
                loadData()
            }
   ```

   }
4. set `ReminderListDataSource`  as a delegate when creating `ReminderRepository`

   ```
    override init() {
    remindersRepository = ReminderRepository()
    remindersRepository.delegate = self
   ```

   }
5. load data after reminder is set

   ```
    func loadData() {
    print ("loadData")
    remindersCollection.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
            self.reminders = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                do {
                    let reminder = try document.data(as: Reminder.self)
                    print ("loadData: ", reminder?.title ?? "Unknown")
                    delegate?.reloadYourData()
                    return reminder
                } catch {
                    print (error)
                }
                return nil
            }
        }
        print ("loadData: ", self.reminders.count)
    }
   ```

   }

Comment: thanks. I'll have a go at this when I get home.

Comment: Hi again. I got stuck at step 2. I created the protocol successfully. But, if you look at the ReminderListDataSource file (from the Apple link provided above), they have a `class ReminderListDataSource: NSObject` followed by an `extension ReminderListDataSource: UITableViewDataSource`. I tried applying your step 2 first to the class, then the extension, but I get the same error message both times: "Reference to member 'reloadData' cannot be resolved without a contextual type."

Comment: I made the `ReminderListViewController` conform to the delegate protocol and followed the rest of the steps, but still the initial screen is blank....

Comment: Then you need to set remindersRepository.delegate = YourReminderListViewController. Does it work then ?

Comment: Will need to try. I think I did try what you said, but I'll double\check.

Comment: IT WORKS! I went back to your original answer, but had to make some adjustments. Step 1 - no change. #2 - `UITableViewController` conforms to protocol, not the `DataSource`.  #3 - no change. #4 - in `UITableViewController`, `reminderListDataSource?.reminderRepository.delegate = self` but when I did that a few days ago, I mistakenly put it *after* the `tableView.dataSource = reminderListDataSource` line. It works *before*. #5 - need to `self.` and moved the line after the `self.reminders … {}` lines. Now it loads upon launch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing `var reminders = [Reminder]()` to

```
var reminders : [Reminder] = []{
   didSet {
      self.tableview.reloadData()
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but: "`ReminderRepository` has no member tableView". The Repository is unconnected to the UI, so it knows nothing about the `tableView`.

Comment: So please implement a method there to reload the tableview. didSet works when any changes happens to your object. So when any new object is getting added to reminders, did set will be invoked and hence you can reload the tableview there.

Comment: Yes, I know about `didSet`, but the repository doesn't have access to the `tableView`. You can get the code from the link I provided and add the code I posted and you'll see that your suggestion doesn't work.